# Django - Get Object with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

versions:
Python 3.4
Django 1.7

I created a gallery app with different galleries and their own images.

my models:

```
from django.db import models


class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publish date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publish date')
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/gallery/'+str(Gallery.objects.get(pk=str(gallery)).id)+'/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

you see my **Gallery** and **Image** model. While creating an **Image** in the Backend it should create a folder dynamicly in *"img/gallery/gallery_id"*

my problem is that **Image.gallery** is a ForeignKey here and I cant convert it into a int or string to use it. Is there a function to get the ID from my **Gallery** object with the ForeignKey from my **Image** object?

my solution

```
Gallery.objects.get(pk=str(gallery)).id
```

is not working.

btw: I thought foreignkey is always an int like id? isnt it?

Comment: You can access the id directly via a hidden field, FOO_id (gallery_id in your case). The gallery field should be an object, but there is a shortcut (aka magic) in Django queries that allows you to pass it as a filter on id / pk without converting it : `Gallery.objects.get(id=gallery).id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Django works, a convenient method is automatically added that will give you the model instance that the foreign key represents. This is your `gallery` field. There is another field, called the same but with `_id` appended, that holds the actual foreign key value.

As petkostas said, you can pass a function that accepts the `instance` and `filename` arguments. You should use `gallery_id` instead of `gallery.id` to prevent an unnecessary call to the database.

```
def gallery_folder(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['img/gallery', instance.gallery_id, filename])

class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=gallery_folder)
```

Comment: Missed that, well spotted.

Comment: thx for your answers guys! but now I get an other error msg while creating an Image in the BE. 

do I have to pass parameters here?
    `file = models.ImageField(upload_to=gallery_folder)`

or can I just c&p your edits?

my error: **TypeError at /admin/gallery/image/add/
sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found** (it is shown on the website not while starting the server)

Comment: @Dude You should pass the function object itself (`gallery_folder`), not a call to the function (`gallery_folder(...)`). Can you post the full traceback in your question?

Answer (score 2):

upload to can be a callback:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

so:

```
def gallery_folder(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['img/gallery', instance.gallery.id, filename])

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publish date')
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=gallery_folder)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Also add related_name, makes reverse queries easier, also you can opt for `instance.gallery.title` if you want.